# Cascading DropdownList for Asp.Net MVC with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to have a pair of cascading drop downs that narrow down a list of cities based on a selected state. So far I have this:
View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollLocation,  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownList("stateCol", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }, optionLabel: "Select a state")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CollLocation", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }, optionLabel: "Select a city")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

And this controller:

```
// GET: Coll/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var stateColl = db.ZipCodes.OrderBy(c => c.state).Select(c => c.state).Distinct();

    var cityCol = db.ZipCodes.Select(C => C.primary_city).Distinct();

    ViewBag.stateCol = new SelectList(stateColl);
    ViewBag.ArRecID = new SelectList(db.ArRecs, "ArRecID", "ArZipID");
    ViewBag.CollLocation = new SelectList(cityCol);
    return View();
}

// POST: Coll/Create

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CollID,ArRecID,CollName,CollDescr,CollValue,CollOwner,CollLocation,DateCreated,ModBy,ModDate,CreatedBy")] Collateral collateral)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Coll.Add(coll);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ArRecID = new SelectList(db.ArRecs, "ArRecID", "ArZipID", coll.ArRecID);
    ViewBag.CollLocation = new SelectList(db.ZipCodes, "zip", "primary_city", coll.CollLocation).Distinct();
    return View(collateral);
}
```

In my ZipCodes model I have zip, primary_city, and state. In the CollLocation, I want to be able to see only the cites that are in the state selected in the stateCol dropdown. Both the drop downs work for me but, they're not working together. I tried other tutorial and answers, butt they only left me scratching my head even more. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommend you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - you need ajax for this to work, but there are multiple other issues with your code

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a great fiddle. It's helping and clearing up a lot of my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make Ajax request every time when you change your State dropdown. Thus, when State dropdown changed, a JavaScript function should make an Ajax request to your controller to query the Zipcode you want.

You can download my project in Github and have a look 2 files"\Views\ClientOrder\Create.cshtml" and  "\RiceStoreScripts\ClientOrder.js"

[hongyichao/MVCRiceStore](https://github.com/hongyichao/MVCRiceStore)